# Removing lines from dsget in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing a script that queries AD to pull out necessary information for a separation termination to occur.  My batch script is as follows

```
echo Please enter the employee's name below...
echo.
echo.
set /p first="First Name: "
set /p last="Last Name: "
echo.
Title %first% %last%'s information...
echo Please wait while information is loaded...
echo.
echo.
echo.


echo                                 Username: 
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dsquery user -name "*%last%* *%first%*"') do set UserID=%%i
echo %UserID%
echo Username: %UserID% >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Termination\%first%%last%.txt


echo                                  Office 
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 skip=1 delims=" %%A in (`"echo %UserID% | dsget user -office"`) do (set "Office=%%A")
echo %Office%
pause
```

The first part is done correctly but when it tries to pull the office information, the script just crashes.  The reason I am doing it this way is because if I just perform the echo %UserID% | dsget user -office it will output

```
office
 XX-XX-XX
dsget suceeded
```

I only want the middle line that is the actual office location set to the variable Office.

I have looked over many of the solutions on here but I cannot seem to get it to work right.  I am wondering if it is because of the way I echo and then pipe.

The reason echo %UserID% | dsget user -office uses the variable is because it performs the search much faster than if it has to redo the dsquery.

Any help y'all can give me would be fantastic!

Thank you

EDIT:

Okay so I was missing the ^ (What does that do anyway)
My code is now

```
echo                                  Office 
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem echo %UserID% | dsget user -office
echo Before >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Termination\%first%%last%.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1 skip=1 delims=" %%A in (`echo %UserID%^| dsget user -office`) do (set "Office=%%A")
echo After >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Termination\%first%%last%.txt
echo %Office%
echo %Office% >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Termination\%first%%last%.txt
echo After echoing variable >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Termination\%first%%last%.txt
```

It no longer crashes but tells me

```
The system cannot find the file 'echo
ECHO is off.
```

as well as outputting all three echo statements

Hopefully last EDIT:

My code is currently

```
echo                                  Office 
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Before >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Termination\%first%%last%.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1 skip=1 delims=" %%A in ('echo %UserID%^|dsget user -office^|Find /V "office"^|Find /V "dsget"') do (set "office=%%A")
echo After >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Termination\%first%%last%.txt
echo Office: %office% >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Termination\%first%%last%.txt
echo After echoing variable >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Termination\%first%%last%.txt
```

It is not outputting anything except the "Office: "  I don't think anything is being saved in the variable office so it is not outputting anything.

EDITED AGAIN:

So if I do `echo %UserID%^|dsget user -office` I will get the following result

[image]

I included the find commands to only keep the middle line.  I would then like the middle line to output to a variable that can be referenced later.  The problem is the way the code is now, it does not output a variable it is just blank.

Comment: did you try without double quote : `('echo %UserID% ^| dsget user -office')`

Comment: There is no need to use the `USEBACKQ` option.  You are not using single quotes in your command as far as I can see.  Just use single quotes and escape the PIPE as SachDee has pointed out.

Comment: @SachaDee I was missing the ^ I updated my code now.  It doesn't crash which is great but it is so close!  Any other ideas?

Comment: @SchurrThing, you are using a back quote.  You need to use a single quote.

Comment: @Squashman well that was foolish of me.  Okay one last edit.  It is not outputting %office% it is almost like it isn't storing anything.  Thanks for your help so far.  Quick question what does ^ do?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do with this code: `'echo %UserID%^|dsget user -office^|Find /V "office"^|Find /V "dsget"'`.  I cannot test the output of this command.  But if you could edit your question to show us the output of the dsget command we could probably help you get the output you want.

Comment: @Squashman picture has been included as well as better explanation

Comment: Do you think it would take more time to post a picture or copy and paste the text from the output?

Comment: @Squashman well I thought you wanted to see the actual output as it was on my screen.  The text version was earlier in the post.  I apologize if I did something wrong?